# HTML вместо Json Python Requests

Tags: python, requests

Знакомлюсь с http запросами в python и получаю в ответ html, вместо json.
Передаю в header `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`.
Что еще можно попробовать?

Comment: добавьте в вопрос ваш код ([править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1280690/edit))

Comment: А почему вы решили, что ответ должен быть именно json?

Comment: Покажите ваш код. Может надо просто метод `.json()` от запроса вызвать